# Lombok doesn't generate getters and setters in STS

Tags: java, lombok, sts

I have followed all the steps to install Lombok and I can see Lombok is installed in my IDE (STS) from help -> eclipse marketplace. But in my model class the getters and setters are not generated.

Comment: Did you enable annotation processing? Can you show your model class? Can you show your build files?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I resolved it at last by adding the @Data annotation in the model class.

Answer (score -1):

Try by just downloading the lombok jar and executing it.